# Count increments by one too many. Input printed too many times. Python

Tags: python

```
def key(shift):
    data = []
    string = input("Please enter the string you wish to decode.\n")
    for i in string:
        if i.strip() and i in ALPHABET:
            data.append(ALPHABET[(ALPHABET.index(i) - shift) % 26])
        else:
            data.append(i)
    output = ''.join(data)
    return output

def run():

    data = []
    count = 0
    shift = 0
    for shift in range (26):
        count +=1
        if key(shift) == "hello world":
            print("Decoded.")
        else:
            print("Not this time!")
        print(count)
        print(key(shift))
```

When I run my program, it should execute "Decoded" at count 3, since it takes 3 shifts to decode khoor zruog into hello world. Moreover, the input "Please enter the string you wish to decode" should be printed once, rather than so many times.

```
Please enter the string you wish to decode.
khoor zruog
Not this time!
1
Please enter the string you wish to decode.
khoor zruog
khoor zruog
Please enter the string you wish to decode.
khoor zruog
Not this time!
2
Please enter the string you wish to decode.
khoor zruog
jgnnq yqtnf
Please enter the string you wish to decode.
khoor zruog
Not this time!
3
Please enter the string you wish to decode.
khoor zruog
ifmmp xpsme
Please enter the string you wish to decode.
khoor zruog
Decoded.
4
Please enter the string you wish to decode.
khoor zruog
hello world
Please enter the string you wish to decode.
```

This is what happens when I try to execute the code. I don't know why it is incrementing to 0, and I don't know why it is asking me the input so many times. Can anyone help me please?

EDIT:

```
def key(shift,string):
    data = []
    for i in string:
        if i.strip() and i in ALPHABET:
            data.append(ALPHABET[(ALPHABET.index(i) - shift) % 26])
        else:
            data.append(i)
    output = ''.join(data)
    return output

def run():
    data = []
    string = input("Please enter the string you wish to decode.\n")
    plaintext = input("Please enter plaintext word.\n")
    count = 0
    shift = 1
    for shift in range (26):
        count +=1
        if plaintext in key(shift,string):
            print(key(shift,string))
            print("The key is: ", count)
            print("Decoded.")
            break
        else:
            print(key(shift,string))
            print("Not this time!")
        print(count)
```

Comment: You told it to repeat the loop 26 times.  If you want to exit early, look up the `break` statement -- which is included in your materials on looping.

Comment: You were right, thank you so much!

Comment: Regarding your last point, your statement `string = input("Please enter...` is inside the `key()` function, which means that it will request input everytime you call `key(shift)`, which you do in your `if` block and again in your `print()` statement. Consider moving the assignment out of your loop, or your input call outside the looped function

Comment: Edited post with updated code. Another issue, it is now telling me count is 4 when I run the program. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

your string

```
string = input("Please enter the string you wish to decode.\n")
```

is inside the function which is called inside the for loop. that's why you are getting print statement multiple times!

remove that input statement and your decoded problem will get solved.